# Json Parsing, need to get key name from response not key value

Tags: json, parsing, android-studio, response

Json Response :

response :{"status":false,"Message":"Some DataBase Error"}

- Requirement :

**i want key name i.e. Message** not value of Message

Code :

```
private final String KEY_MSG = "Message";
private final String KEY_MSG1 = "message";

try {
            AppLog.Log("TAG123", response);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String message1="Message";
            if (message1.equals(jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG)))
            {
                AppLog.Log("fgesarfefe", "dsfdsfdsfds");
                return jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG);

            }
            else
            {
                AppLog.Log("00000000", "111111");
                return jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG1);
            }
           /* if (jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG).equals("message"))
            {
                return jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG1);
            }
           else
            {*/
              //  return jsonObject.getString(KEY_MSG);
           // }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "No data";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject.keySet()` method to get the set of keys on that object. In your case, it should return **"status"** and **"Message"**.

In case you want to get individual key, you can iterate using :

```
for (String jsonKey : jsonObject.keySet()) {
     // Check each key here, jsonKey value will be "status" and "Message"
}
```

Hope this helps, good luck